# What is the best way to process options in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

I have created a WordPress plugin based around site optimization. The plugin has a lot of options and depending on which options are checked, it enables a function (or code).

Currently, I am processing the options like this:

```
update_option('new_plugin_options',implode("\n",$_POST['options_full']));

$options_full = get_option( 'new_plugin_options');

if ( strpos($options_full, 'setting_name') === false ) {} else {
  //code
}
```

I read that strpos is the least resource-intensive way to match items, so I decided to go that route. However, I'm not convinced this is the optimal way, as we are dealing with 60+ options/functions/codes that need to run.

Is there a faster/better way?

Comment: Don't use `implode` just save the array value, WordPress will take care of the array automatically and when you use `get_option` you'll get an array again.

Comment: @Vijay Hardaha Are you saying that Wordpress will automatically serialize and unserialize the array? I didn't know that...

Comment: Yes, WordPress will take care of that in options, post meta, and user meta. you don't need to do anything special for that.

Comment: @Vijay Hardaha But even if the array was automatically serialized/unserialized, wouldn't you have to use in_array (a more resource-intensive code) to see which options were selected? Or implode the array and then use strpos, resulting in the same thing?

Comment: You will use `$options_full['setting_name']` to get the setting by key name and you can also perform `isset` check if the key exists or not.